# How to load an Office add-in already installed from an external program in c#?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, add-in, excel-addins

I'm developing an add-in for Power Point with VSTO in c#, it's already installed but not loaded on the startup of power point. 
I whant an external program to lounch Power Point (already solved), and when lounched make Power Point to load the add-in.

I have found the AddIns inside Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application, but i don't know if thats the way to do it.

I don't whant the add-in to load every time i open Power Point.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting the add-in's .Loaded property to true?

Comment: That sound like a good solution, but how can i get the add-in object?
I have:
**Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();**

but when i check ppApp.AddIns.Count the value is 0.

Comment: I found my add-in inside the ppApp.COMAddIns, now i'm trying to load it, but ther is no .Loaded property in com addins, any idea?

Comment: Ah, COM add-in. Sorry, should have realized that what with VSTO and all.  I don't know how you'd do this, but there's an Applicatio.COMaddins.Connect property that's read/write.  That might help.